# Angular 2 - Display variable inside a variable in a template

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, binding

I'm quite new in Angular 2, and I want to show in my template a string in a variable that has to contain inside another variable. I will show you a simplified example of what my problem is and what I want to achieve:

---

**questionnaire.component.ts**

```
/* Starts being "", populating an input text will modify this */
name = "Albert";

/* This variable comes from calling an API, here I just put it as created to simplify */
question.title = "Hello {{name}}, how old are you?";
```

**questionnaire.template.html**

```
<p>{{question.title}}</p>
```

---

The result I'm getting is:

> Hello {{name}}, how old are you?

and my desired result would be:

> Hello Albert, how old are you?

I have tried to escape the "{{ }}" in the string stored on my DB, used the ASCII character instead of the curly braces, put it inside *[innerHTML]*... but the result was always the same.

Do you know how can I solve this?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`{{}}` only works in Angular component templates and not in arbitrary strings and also not in HTML added dynamically to the DOM.

Just change it to

```
 question.title = `Hello ${this.name}, how old are you?`;
```

to use TypeScript string interpolation.

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. I guess it will also work if I get the object "question" from DB calling an API directly if the "title" field is `Hello ${this.name}...`, won't it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that means exactly. It depends on where you put your code and if `this.name` is available from where the code is executed, but in principle this works everywhere in TS code.

Comment: Ok, don't worry, will try to try it myself and see if it works in my particular case. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Thanks for this solution, Initially was not working for me but that was because I was using single quotes and not backticks!

Answer (score 0):

In angular2 you have to use **this**  keyword

For example, ${this.name}